# How to Enable the LDAP for Teradata Vantage Express 17.20 On VM

Tags: ldap, teradata

I am trying to enable LDAP for Teradata Vantage Express 17.20. I have Vantage installed on a VM and also enabled the LDAP for Windows Server 2019.

When I followed the documentation, I discovered that I needed to install GSS on the vantage VM. However, on the download section of TeraData, nothing was found with the name GSS.
I found another [article](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB46043-How-to-setup-Teradata-database-server-to-authenticate?language=ja) When I followed that I got stuck with the point where I should run this command `./tsbind -u ldapusername` Under  `/opt/teradata/tdgss/bin` Path. When I looked into it there was no file with the name tsbind.

I have looked for this file nothing was found. On the [Documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/Security-Administration/Introduction-to-Security-Administration/Changes-and-Additions), I found this

tdsbind was deprecated in release 17.10. Teradata recommends using the tdgssauth tool. Documentation for tdsbind is removed in release 17.20.
The SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication protocol used by LDAP was deprecated in release 17.10 and must not be used. Use simple binding with TLS protection instead. Documentation for SASL/DIGEST-MD5 is removed in release 17.20.

Will anyone help to solve this problem? Can I enable LDAP or Not if not what can I use instead of LDAP for Teradata? Any Document blog post or suggestion will be very helpful.

It would be a great help if you please advise me on this matter.

------------------------------ UPDATE -------------------------------
I have follow the new documentation but I stuck again on the same place. I have updated the file as follow `/opt/teradata/tdat/tdgss/site/TdgssUserConfigFile.xml`

```
<MechanismProperties
                AuthenticationSupported="yes"
                AuthorizationSupported="no"
                MechanismEnabled="yes"
                MechanismRank="70"
                DefaultMechanism="no"
                DelegateCredentials="no"
                MutualAuthentication="yes"
                ReplayDetection="yes"
                OutOfSequenceDetection="yes"
                ConfidentialityDesired="yes"
                IntegrityDesired="yes"
                AnonymousAuthentication="no"
                DesiredContextTime=""
                DesiredCredentialTime=""
                CredentialUsage="0"
                LdapClientMechanism="simple"
                LdapServicePasswordProtected="yes"
                VerifyDHKey="no"

                DHKeyP="000000000000"
                DHKeyG="000000000000"

                LdapServerName="123.123.123.123"
                LdapServerPort="389"
                LdapServerRealm="testdomain.com"
                LdapBaseFQDN="dc=testdomain,dc=com"
                LdapServiceFQDN="cn=myusername,ou=Users,ou=TDLDAP,dc=testdomain,dc=com"
                LdapServicePassword="myencriptedpassword"
                LdapServiceBindRequired="yes"
                />
```

I have also added the Identitysearch as I was facing one error as recommended from [here](https://support.teradata.com/community?id=kb_article&sys_id=d22884cc47674d548cf4f352846d434d).

```
       <IdentitySearch
          Match="(.*)"
          Base="dc=testdomain,dc=internal"
          Scope="Subtree"
          Filter="(sAMAccountname=${0})"
       />
```

However when I run

```
/opt/teradata/tdgss/bin/tdgssauth -u myusernamefromAD -m ldap -i 123.123.123.123
```

I see this error

```
TDGSS_BIN_FILE not set.
TDGSSCONFIG GDO used in tdgss.
Please enter a password:

The TDGSS function tdgss_accept_sec_context returned an error
  Major status 0x000d0000 - Failure
  Minor status 0xe3000233 - No matching canonicalizations available.
teradata@VantageExpress1710-Sles12:/root> timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
```

Any help please ?

Comment: The tsbind is a typo but as you discovered tdsbind is no longer present in 17.20. See also the section "LDAP Binding Options" in the same document referenced above. Or you could use native database authentication (TD2).

Comment: Hi Fred, I am facing the same error after following the new setup. I am not using the TLS or any certificate but it should not be the problem I guess. I have updated the Quest can you please have a look?

Comment: Where is the canonical name for myusernamefromAD in the directory hierarchy? I would have expected the IdentitySearch Base to end with something like `dc=com`